# Creating an update to Fiscal Year based on Month Error

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to troubleshoot an EOF error with this SQL. I'm really new to SQL server scripting so any other critique appreciated here. I'm trying to:

1. Convert StartTime to a mm/dd/yy format
2. Look at the month, which should either add a year or leave it alone ( July - Dec add 1 year )
3. Encase that in a variable type thing called NewDate
4. Use NewDate as the Value for a new column called zrefFiscalYear

Adding the column zrefFiscalYear

```
AlTER Table Reservation
Add zrefFiscalYear datetime;
```

This top select is the EOF error Missing EOF at Select

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar, StartTime, 1) as [MM/DD/YY]
SELECT 
 CASE 
   WHEN MONTH(StartTime) > 7 THEN YEAR(StartTime) + 1
   ELSE YEAR(StartTime) + 0
 END AS NewDate
 FROM Reservation; 
Update Reservation
Set zrefFiscalYear = YEAR(NewDate);
```

Comment: `Add zrefFiscalYear datetime` Nope - this is, by your own definition and discussion, a **DATE**. Stop adding additional risk with the inclusion of time.

Answer (score 2):

Hmmm . . . I'm not sure what `[MM/DD/YY]` is doing. Dates are stored using an internal format.  If you want to present it as a particular format, then you convert it to a string *when you query the table*.

But the fiscal year part is simply:

```
UPDATE Reservation
    SET zrefFiscalYear = (CASE WHEN MONTH(StartTime) > 7
                               THEN YEAR(NewDate) + 1 ELSE YEAR(NewDate)
                          END);
```

Note that you don't even need to store this in the table.  You *could* use a computed column:

```
ALTER TABLE Reservation ADD zrefFiscalYear AS
    (CASE WHEN MONTH(StartTime) > 7
          THEN YEAR(NewDate) + 1 ELSE YEAR(NewDate)
     END);
```

This has the advantage that the value is always up-to-date.

EDIT:

I think I misread the question, so `NewDate` is not in the table, only `StartTime`.  So, you can use two computed columns:

```
ALTER TABLE Reservation
    ADD newDate AS (CONVERT(DATE, StartTime)),
        zrefFiscalYear AS
            (CASE WHEN MONTH(StartTime) > 7
                  THEN YEAR(StartTime) + 1 ELSE YEAR(StartTime)
             END);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=840459ed727b1433e9f61936a19aa763) is a db<>fiddle.

Comment: Thanks. I get two syntax errors on this based on what you did.                                         ALTER TABLE Reservation ADD zrefFiscalYear AS
    (CASE WHEN MONTH(StartTime) > 7
          THEN YEAR(zrefFiscalYear) + 1 ELSE YEAR(zrefFiscalYear) END);  it doesn't like the AS, but I have no idea why this shouldn't work.